Plot modification for sensitivity analysis
Hello I have this result plot for my work.

There the metric 'weight' is plotted as a function of the parameter $\alpha$, and this for different values of $\gamma$. These are the results of a MILP, with people, a planning period and the number of calories eaten per day. Now I want to perform sensitivity analyses with regard to 1) the number of people and 2) the average number of calories eaten per day and then plot this again. I want to examine a higher and a lower gradation in both dimensions. How could I then integrate the results into the plot above or are there possibly better plots? I want to analyze each dimension separately but am also open to ideas for a simultaneous analysis.
